# assert additional parameter to pandas dataframe records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I got a rather large pandas dataframe (5k rows, 30 cols). I need to do  as described below. I tried

```
pseudocode

for i in main_df.iterrows():
    for j in sub_df.iterrows():
        if j == part of i:
            i["sub_uid"] = j["sub_uid"]
```

But this does not seem to work, or is just too hard to debug for me. (is also absurdly time consuming)

I am basically out of ideas and hope for your help guys :)

```
    main_df:
        v1  v2  vx3 vx4
    1   a   b   h   j
    2   a   b   n   p
    3   a   c   r   g
    4   d   e   p   j
    
    sub_df: take only part of main_df columns, drop duplicates. Assign uids for all combinations of v1 v2 parameters
        v1  v2  sub_uid
    1   a   b   01
    2   a   c   02
    3   d   e   03
    
    now back to main_df: add a column for sub_uids. For each record, determine sub_uid using sub_df
        v1  v2  vx3 vx4 sub_uid
    1   a   b   h   j   01
    2   a   b   n   p   01
    3   a   c   r   g   02
    4   d   e   p   j   03
```

Comment: Why not `merge` the two data frames on `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: @Parfait yep, thats it. merging solves the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to directly assign `sub_uid` to `main_df` without creating `sub_df`:

```
In [2473]: df['sub_uid'] = df.groupby(['v1', 'v2']).ngroup().add(1)

In [2474]: df
Out[2474]: 
  v1 v2 vx3 vx4  sub_uid
1  a  b   h   j        1
2  a  b   n   p        1
3  a  c   r   g        2
4  d  e   p   j        3
```

Comment: It seems to be sufficient, but would require reparsing uids to custom strings. Probably GroupBy.groups would do the job with a generated dictionary. I will investigate later, for now I`ll stick to merge that Parfait suggested.

Comment: My understanding of your question was that, you only have `main_df` and you want to append `sub_uid` to it. So I gave you a direct way of doing that avoiding creating intermediate `sub_df` and using `merge` to reach where I already am.